# Segmentation fault (program cc1plus) when compile code with "ROS_ERROR_STREAM()"

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile Autoware.io on Nvidia Jetson Xavier .

Package name : lanelet2_extension (package in Autoware.io, source code from https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai)

Jetson Xavier core architecture is ARMv8

```
OS version：Linux nvidia-desktop 4.9.253-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 26 12:19:28 PDT 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Distributor ID:   Ubuntu

Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Release:  18.04

Codename: bionic

```
ROS version: melodic
```

Error msg:

```
c++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/utilities-test.dir/test/src/test_utilities.cpp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/utilities-test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tests.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [tests] Error 2
    GCC version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

BTW, I tried to compile the code with gcc 5.5, the problem still exists.

I noticed another Q&A (https://answers.ros.org/question/97441/c-compiler-crashed/), so I commented part of the code，such as "ROS_ERROR_STREAM(**FUNCTION** << "msg is null pointer!");" and so on. Finally, the code can be compiled correctly

so, how should I investigate the cause of the error in depth? Seems to be caused by stream output?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392872/segmentation-fault-(program-cc1plus)-when-compile-code-with-%22ros_error_stream()%22/) by [Samuel_Leon_Fisher](https://answers.ros.org/users/91617/samuel_leon_fisher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I may have solved this problem.

Maybe the stack size is too small. I increased the stack limit to 8192 and the problem was resolved.

To modify the stack size, please modify the file "/etc/security/limits.conf"

---

Originally posted by [Samuel_Leon_Fisher](https://answers.ros.org/users/91617/samuel_leon_fisher/) with karma: 26 on 2021-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-18**:
Glad you found an answer @Samuel_Leon_Fisher. Thank you for sharing